# Kafka connect and HDFS in docker

Tags: docker, hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka connect HDFS sink and Hadoop (for HDFS) in a docker-compose.

Hadoop (namenode and datanode) seems working correctly.

But I have an error with kafka connect sink:

```
ERROR Recovery failed at state RECOVERY_PARTITION_PAUSED 
(io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter:277) 
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: 
Error creating writer for log file hdfs://namenode:8020/logs/MyTopic/0/log
```

For information:

- Hadoop services in my docker-compose.yml:

  ```
  namenode:
    image: uhopper/hadoop-namenode:2.8.1
    hostname: namenode
    container_name: namenode
    ports:
      - "50070:50070"
    networks:
      default:
      fides-webapp:
        aliases:
          - "hadoop"
    volumes:
      - namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=hadoop-cluster

  datanode1:
    image: uhopper/hadoop-datanode:2.8.1
    hostname: datanode1
    container_name: datanode1
    networks:
      default:
      fides-webapp:
        aliases:
          - "hadoop"
    volumes:
      - datanode1:/hadoop/dfs/data
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  ```

And my kafka-connect file:

```
    name=hdfs-sink
    connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
    tasks.max=1
    topics=MyTopic
    hdfs.url=hdfs://namenode:8020
    flush.size=3
```

**EDIT:**

I add an env variable for kafka connect to be aware of the cluster name (env variable: CLUSTER_NAME to add in kafka connect service in docker compose file).

The error is not the same (and it seems to solve a problem):

```
INFO Starting commit and rotation for topic partition scoring-topic-0 with start offsets {partition=0=0} and end offsets {partition=0=2} 
 (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter:368)
ERROR Exception on topic partition MyTopic-0: (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.TopicPartitionWriter:403)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): 
File /topics/+tmp/MyTopic/partition=0/bc4cf075-ccfa-4338-9672-5462cc6c3404_tmp.avro 
could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  
There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

**EDIT2:**

The `hadoop.env` file is:

```
    CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020

    # Configure default BlockSize and Replication for local
    # data. Keep it small for experimentation.
    HDFS_CONF_dfs_blocksize=1m

    YARN_CONF_yarn_log___aggregation___enable=true
    YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_recovery_enabled=true
    YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_store_class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore
    YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_fs_state___store_uri=/rmstate
    YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_remote___app___log___dir=/app-logs

    YARN_CONF_yarn_log_server_url=http://historyserver:8188/applicationhistory/logs/
    YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_enabled=true
    YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_generic___application___history_enabled=true
    YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_system___metrics___publisher_enabled=true

    YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_hostname=resourcemanager
    YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_hostname=historyserver
```

Comment: Is your Kafka Connect part of the same Docker Compose file? If not, are the services on the same docker network?

Comment: Yes kafka-connect is in the same docker compose file. Kafka connect seems to create the folder in HDFS but it's not writing in this. I change an env variable and I have a new error. I edit the post.

Comment: Yes, the tmp directory is used to keep data until a file is created with the messages.... From the error, your datanode container is not healthy or you need to define a `hadoop.home` variable in Connect that is used to load the Hadoop configuration files from inside the containers. Please edit your question to include the `hadoop.env` and show the other containers. For the Confluent images, I don't think cluster name is a used variable

Comment: I add `hadoop.env` file. I do not use confluent image for kafka connect. I build my own image based on `openjdk:8-jre-alpine` and `confluent 4.0`.

Comment: Are you able to exec into the namenode container and run `hdfs dfs -put` commands successfully? On the namenode UI, are the datanodes listed as healthy?

Comment: Yes, I execute command at the end of this [blog post](https://codito.in/hadoop-cluster-in-docker/) and I can insert data into hdfs. Evrything seems fine in the namenode UI.

Comment: I'm sure Hadoop all works, but for Kafka Connect to connect to Hadoop, it typically needs more than just a namenode connection, and you set that by getting the XML files out of the Hadoop servers, and then copying them to `hadoop.conf.dir` Kafka Connect property

Comment: Thanks a lot it works when I copy hadoop conf to the docker image containing kafka connect. I ahev to find a way to automate that but it's a workaround for now :). I let you post an answer :)

Comment: I think it would need to be a shell script like `start-hadoop; docker cp datanode:/etc/hadoop/conf .; start-kafka-connect`

Comment: My solution consists in a named volume shared between namenode and kafka connect containing the conf files

Comment: Feel free to show your complete answer below to help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly like noticed by @cricket_007 I need to configure `hadoop.conf.dir`.

The directory should contain `hdfs-site.xml`.

When each service is dockerized, I need to create a named volume in order to share configuration files between `kafka-connect` service and `namenode` service.

To do this I add in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
  hadoopconf:
```

Then for `namenode` service I add:

```
volumes:
  - hadoopconf:/etc/hadoop
```

And for kafka connect service:

```
volumes:
    - hadoopconf:/usr/local/hadoop-conf
```

Finaly I set `hadoop.conf.dir` in my HDFS sink properties file to `/usr/local/hadoop-conf`.